How to help 13 year old to be more open, motivated and responsible
I have a son - 13 yrs old. He is doing well in his school gifted in both Math and Language arts.
But he has a few behavioral / personality issues that seem to be bothering us especially now since he is reaching his puberty age and looking for more independence.

He is not particularly strong willed. He tried a few things and giving up as soon as he think it is too hard for him. For ex. I enrolled him in karate class at the age of 6, he reached very close to black belt but now left it since he is finding it too hard.
He is too picky in eating, small for his age and he seems to have accepted it that he is different from his peers but at the same time he also feels inferior that he is small and not as strongly built as his peers.
He is not physically too active, he likes to lie around play games or watch vidoes from his favorite youtube channel and gets less involved in physical activities. To motivate him, we got a table tennis table, pickle ball set, swimming twice a week, tennis classes, badminton etc. And I encourage him to come join with me and his younger brother playing these games and other board games and family activities but none of these interests him.
Till now he used to read a lot but now he also lost interest in reading.
The biggest issue now I am facing is he is not motivated to do anything. He has in front of him his 2 yr younger brother who is so much into trying all sorts of things, trying all kinds of technical things including building his own gaming PC, building custom RC cars, trying all kinds of other STEM experiments his age. I am mentioning his younger brother not to compare both of them but just that his yonger brothers example in front of him doesnt work to motivate him. However whatever little he helped his yonger brother do his stuff, he is quick to take credit for what he did.
He doesnt have friends his age, he talks and likes to hang around with his younger brothers friends. This might be linked to the point 2 above.
He has strong attitude problem which is why he is not a type someone would like to be aroud with. Very quick to blame others for something wrong that happened with him, not willing to take responsibility for his own choices. Likes to argue when you try to talk to him about what he needs to work on or improve upon. Recently his tennis coach complained that he tried to talk to him about what he needs to improve upon, but instead of working on his mistake he argued about what his coach did wrong.
Clumsy. I have to keep reminding him about tying his shoe laces, brushing his teeth, combing his hairs, cleaning his room etc. He is very forgetful and keeps missing his basic chores.

Things I do as his dad -

I spend a lot of time with him take him to swimming, tennis, frisby, badminton etc. Also play family board games, chess and ping-pong.
I read a lot, about 2-3 hours a day as a hobby, and I think it may motivate him to restart his reading.
I talk a lot about making healthier eating choices, making better overall/holistic life-style choices.
We always have meals together and I initiate discussion about how he is doing at school, whether he needs any help at anything and a bunch of other family fun/silly talks.

Inspite of all negative points I mentioned in the previous section, one thing never to forget is he is very gentle, sweet and innocent child when all is going well. Very willing to help others with what he is good at.
And I as his dad can relate to all those things mentioned above since I was and still am pretty much the same personality. I hit my maturity age pretty late at around 20-22 yrs and I know no one liked to be around me in my childhood, I learnt my lessons a hard/ugly and painful way and tried to improve upon a bunch of those things which can make me hard to be with.
I know he is just following me, but I just want to see if there is any better way he can learn his lessons, get motivated, be more open to try new things.
I could be doing certain things wrong which is triggering a few of these issues and looking for some suggestions about what I can do to help him grow well.
Please help!

A few things stand out to me here:

he is small for his size
he doesn't have friends his age
he is defensive when people point out his mistakes
you seem to believe that his behavior needs to be fixed, that it requires a project

I'm no psychologist, but this sounds like a self-esteem issue to me. He's got a younger brother that is widely competent and motivated, he's small, has few friends, and people seem to be trying to improve him. That sounds really depressing to me, so I can see where he's coming from.
As for things you can do, some reading on how to build a child's self-esteem might help. I likely can't give you better recommendations than you can find across the internet, but a few thoughts:

he may have some things to work on, but try to realize that people are generally fine as they are. Everyone, everywhere is always growing and learning, he's just at a particular stage of his journey and needs help to get to the next stage. This mostly means being there for him, listening, being a confidant. What it doesn't mean is treating the relationship like a project where you need to point out flaws and improve everything he does. He may be a little immature for his age, but it can only come if he's open to your influence. If you influence without opening the door first, it won't work.
try to realize, embrace, and find all of his positive qualities. What is he good at? What does he like doing? What kind of activities can you suggest that will show him that he is competent in some areas? Motivation generally intersects with desire and ability, so you want to find what he is good at and likes doing, and the motivation may come
more generally just try to enjoy your son, his presence, his being, without the expectation that he needs to become or do anything. You have limited time with him before he moves out, be present and be a friend without judgement or expectation

I think you'll find that when he's treated as an equal, a friend, and knows he is loved, that's when you might get a crack into the ability to influence.
